# Optimizing SQL query to return Record with tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I was looking for help to optimize a query I am writing for SQL Server. Given this database schema:

TradeLead object, a record in this table is a small article.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TradeLeads]
(
    [TradeLeadID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Title nvarchar(250),
    Body nvarchar(max),
    CreateDate datetime,
    EditDate datetime,
    CreateUser nvarchar(250),
    EditUser nvarchar(250), 
    [Views] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)

)
```

Here's the cross reference table to link a TradeLead article to an Industry record.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TradeLeads_Industries]
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [TradeLeadID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [IndustryID] INT NOT NULL
)
```

Finally, the schema for the Industry object. These are essentially just tags, but a user is unable to enter these. The database will have a specific amount.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Industries]
(
    IndustryID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(200)
)
```

The procedure I'm writing is used to search for specific TradeLead records. The user would be able to search for keywords in the title of the TradeLead object, search using a date range, and search for a TradeLead with specific Industry Tags.

The database will most likely be holding around 1,000,000 TradeLead articles and about 30 industry tags.

This is the query I have come up with:

```
DECLARE @Title nvarchar(50);
SET @Title = 'Testing';
-- User defined table type containing a list of IndustryIDs. Would prob have around 5 selections max.
DECLARE @Selectedindustryids IndustryIdentifierTable_UDT;
DECLARE @Start DATETIME;
SET @Start = NULL;
DECLARE @End DATETIME;
SET @End = NULL;


SELECT *
FROM(
-- Subquery to return all the tradeleads that match a user's criteria.
-- These fields can be null.
SELECT TradeLeadID, 
            Title, 
            Body, 
            CreateDate, 
            CreateUser, 
            Views
     FROM TradeLeads
     WHERE(@Title IS NULL OR Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%') AND (@Start IS NULL OR CreateDate >= @Start) AND (@End IS NULL OR CreateDate <= @End)) AS FTL

    INNER JOIN
    -- Subquery to return the TradeLeadID for each TradeLead record with related IndustryIDs
    (SELECT TI.TradeLeadID
           FROM TradeLeads_Industries TI
           -- Left join the selected IndustryIDs to the Cross reference table to get the TradeLeadIDs that are associated with a specific industry.
           LEFT JOIN @SelectedindustryIDs SIDS
             ON SIDS.IndustryID = TI.IndustryID
           -- It's possible the user has not selected any IndustryIDs to search for.
           WHERE (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @SelectedIndustryIDs) OR SIDS.IndustryID IS NOT NULL)
           -- Group by to reduce the amount of records.
           GROUP BY TI.TradeLeadID) AS SelectedIndustries ON SelectedIndustries.TradeLeadID = FTL.TradeLeadID



       With about 600,000 TradeLead records and  with an average of 4 IndustryIDs attached to each one, the query takes around 8 seconds to finish on a local machine. I would like to get it as fast as possible. Any tips or insight would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few points here.

Using constructs like `(@Start IS NULL OR CreateDate >= @Start)` can cause a problem called parameter sniffing. Two ways of working around it are

1. Add `Option (Recompile)` to the end of the query
2. Use dynamic SQL to only include the criteria that the user has asked for.

I would favour the second method for this data.

Next, the query can be rewritten to be more efficient by using `exists` (assuming the user has entered industry ids)

```
select
    TradeLeadID, 
    Title, 
    Body, 
    CreateDate, 
    CreateUser, 
    [Views]
from
    dbo.TradeLeads t
where
    Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%' and
    CreateDate >= @Start and
    CreateDate <= @End and
    exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            dbo.TradeLeads_Industries ti
                inner join
            @Selectedindustryids sids
                on ti.IndustryID = sids.IndustryID
        where
            t.TradeLeadID = ti.TradeLeadID
    );
```

Finally you will want at least one index on the `dbo.TradeLeads_Industries` table. The following are candidates.

```
(TradeLeadID, IndustryID)
(IndustryID, TradeLeadID)
```

Testing will tell you whether one or both is useful.